# Is there a way in VS2008 to set MSBuildBinPath to be used for new projects?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, msbuild

I've done a job in an older solution.  I have added a new project to this solution.  For this solution we have to use `Visual Studio 2008` and no project can have a .Net framework newer than 2.0 (because of the server it is installed to have limitations).

Even though the solution builds on my machine we still have to manually edit the project  (`.csproj`) file to set one property specifically:

`<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />`

(which was autogenerated when I added the project) needs to be changed to

`<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />`

to facilitate some arcane build setup that nobody who is working here understand or want to touch.

In [this question/article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/974c382a-06ea-49cb-86bb-8aad80dc2d1c/when-does-visual-studio-use-msbuildtoolspath-instead-of-msbuildbinpath?forum=csharpide) I found the following:

> $(MSBuildToolsPath) is the version-specific replacement for $(MSBuildBinPath).  The older property is still available but should be deprecated.  VS2008 will use the newer path when it creates a project.  Prior to VS2005 the older path was used.  When you upgrade a project from VS2005 to VS2008 it does not modify the path.

Does this mean that somewhere in this build script the path to MSBuildBinPath is hard coded?

Manually changing this is error prone and easy to forget (the *it-builds-on-my-machine* effect).  Is there a way to set it somewhere in VS2008 so that new projects to this solution will get the older property by default in the `.csproj` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing .net 3.5 and VS2008 on the build server? Might be, there's just only .net 2.0 and msbuild 2.0 available on your build server.

I see only 1 option to accomplish what you describe: using a custom project template. I belive it's quite easy to accomplish (given there is a [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms247120%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and you need only a slight modification to default template).

Comment: +1 for guiding me towards project templates.  It looks promising.  I'll check the build server too, when I get the chance.

Comment: The build server does have `.Net 3.5` and `VS2008` installed.  I think your suggestion of project templates is the way to go.  Thanks!

Comment: (if no one comes up with something better in a few days I'll give you the correct answer check)

Comment: >> "The build server does have .Net 3.5 and VS2008 installed" Chances are, they just use msbuild 2.0 to execute the build. I'd try changing it to msbuild 3.5

Comment: You're correct.  The build server uses `MSBuild 2.0`.  Thanks!